# Pivoting Issue (what am I missing)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Trying to pivot data and add a calculated column to no avail.

I have tried the enclosed code below but cannot get exactly what I am after.

My table consists of three columns

TABLE_NAME, REPORT_DATE, COUNT_ROWS

For the last two [REPORT_DATE]s, I am trying to show in a pivot the [COUNT_ROWS] for each [TABLE_NAME]

What am I missing?  Additionally, how would I go about adding a column subtracting the values between the two dates in the pivot?

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(REPORT_DATE) + ',' FROM (select DISTINCT TOP 2 REPORT_DATE from account_report order by  REPORT_DATE desc) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(select  [TABLE_NAME], [COUNT_ROWS] from account_report
) src
pivot 
(sum([COUNT_ROWS]) for [TABLE_NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
```

All I am getting from the script is a two column result of the two [REPORT_DATE]s with 1 row showing null values (although my data does include rows)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are trying to get the following out of the query:

```
SELECT * from 
(select  [TABLE_NAME], [COUNT_ROWS], [REPORT_DATE] from account_report
) src
pivot 
(sum([COUNT_ROWS]) for [REPORT_DATE] in (' + @cols + ')
) piv
```

Conversely, if you really want the report name pushed out columnwise then you need to adjust your `@cols` variable.

```
SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ',' FROM (select DISTINCT TOP 2 TABLE_NAME ,REPORT_DATE from account_report order by  REPORT_DATE desc) as tmp
select @cols = substring(@cols, 0, len(@cols)) --trim "," at end

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(select  [REPORT_DATE], [TABLE_NAME], [COUNT_ROWS] from account_report 
) src
pivot 
(sum([COUNT_ROWS]) for [TABLE_NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
```